# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() when using json_decode

Tags: laravel

When i do check dd($order->customer_id) result will come like this

```
     ["2451","2453","2463","2457","2456","2470","2467","2468","2488","2472","2482","2469","2480"]
```

[image]

i used foreach loop like this.

```
@foreach(json_decode($order->customer_id) as $key => $value)
  <input name="customer_id[]" value="{{ json_decode($order->customer_id)[$key] ?? null }}"                                             
  class="form-control">
 @endforeach
```

But error is coming Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: You don't need json_decode , `$order->customer_id` is already an array

Comment: @sta Actually my data was stored in wrong format like above image.So i changed data fromat in sql like ["2323","23323"] 
 but i donot how these data store in such format and all other data are in array format

Comment: what @sta means to say `@foreach(json_decode($order->customer_id)` you don't need json_decode here

Comment: try `json_decode($order->customer_id, true)`

Comment: Looking at the result of your `dd()` ( the image ), the data is not valid json, so your `json_decode()` won't work. Just try to `dd()` the output of `json_decode`, it will most likely show null

Comment: @ArunAS Yes You are right.The data was not valid Json. Only sometimes Unvalid Json data format will store in database . I donot know why.But thanks for responding